# Crystal Reports Basic - Data Table Displays One Record Per Page

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports Basic in Visual Studio 2008 to print my webform to PDF.  Everything works except I cannot get the data table i created in my dataset to display all results in a table like format.  It creates a page for each record returned with one result per page.  I created a dataset with a datatable in it and am databinding in vb.  Like I said, everything works except it returns a single page for each result returned in my data table.  How do I get it to show up in one spot?  I can worry about formatting lines and grids later, I just need to get it all to show up in one spot on the first page in a row/column type way.

Answer (score 0):

to show a report with many lines per page, you must add your datatable fields in the Detail section of the report. You can include column titles in the Page Header section, so, if your report grows, every page will contain the column titles.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  The problem was that I had so many other things going on in the report I couldn't do it that way.  But I've found a solution.  I added a subreport that was only the datatable I wanted and formatted it as a table.  Now I've got all the data in one spot exactly where I want it on my main report.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Added subreport that only had the datatable information without all the other stuff my main report has on it.  Then I could use the report header in the subreport to create columns and formatted it all as a table.

Answer (score 0):

In the **Section Expert** there are options for each section called **New Page Before** and **New Page After**.  As the names imply, if you turn on these options, Crystal will add a page break before/after each time that section appears.

If you turned on one of these options, then turning it off should fix your problem.